# Impossible to update table1 with condition in table 2

Tags: sql, conditional-statements

I want to update column lasvisit with timestamp and I want join another table because condition it is in this table see my query:

```
UPDATE vld_members SET lastvisit='123456789' 
WHERE 
vld_members as m
INNER JOIN 
vld_members_data_members as md
ON  m.member_id = md.data_id 
WHERE md.data_gender1 = 1
ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 1
```

but it does not work and I test this:

```
UPDATE vld_members SET lastvisit='1517688911' 
WHERE vld_members INNER JOIN vld_members_data_members 
ON  vld_members.member_id = vld_members_data_members.data_id 
WHERE vld_members_data_members.data_gender1 = 1 ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 2
```

not work

but I have 2 query it work:

```
SELECT * 
FROM vld_members as m 
INNER JOIN vld_members_data_members as md on m.member_id = md.data_id 
WHERE md.data_gender1 = 1 ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 5



UPDATE vld_members SET lastvisit='.$var.' 
ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 5
```

work?

Comment: Why do you need `ORDER BY` in Update???

Comment: Which [DBMS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DBMS) product are you using?  "SQL" is just a query language, not the name of a specific database product (and there is no `join` in an UPDATE statement in standard SQL)

Comment: I ask on another forum and someone to find the solution, which I will share with you:

UPDATE vld_members m JOIN (
SELECT data_id FROM vld_members_data_members
WHERE data_gender1 = 1
ORDER BY RAND () LIMIT 5
) AS on m.member_id = md.data_id
SET m.lastvisit = '1402427653'

if that can help someone else

Thanks to you all for your help...

Comment: how to closed this items ?